# How to create custom navigation for each slick slider when there are multiple carousels on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I have a page that has two carousels. I'm using the slick slider plugin and I need to create custom navigation that targets each of the carousel separately.

I'm struggling to figure out how I would do this. At the moment if you click on the navigation for any of the carousels it changes the slides within all the carousels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Heres the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/81t4pkfa/154/

JS

```
$('.test').each(function (idx, item) {
    var carouselId = "carousel" + idx;
    this.id = carouselId;

    $(this).slick({
        slide: "#" + carouselId +" .option",
        arrows: false
    });

    $(".tabs li a").click(function(){
       var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
       $('.test').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/81t4pkfa/153/

```js
$('.test').each(function (idx, item) {
    var carouselId = "carousel" + idx;
    this.id = carouselId;
    $(this).slick({
        slide: "#" + carouselId +" .option",
        arrows: false
    });
});
    $(".tabs li a").click(function(){
      var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
     $(this).parent().parent().parent().slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));
    });
//});
```

```css
.effect {
    margin: 5px 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: 320px;
    text-align: center;
}
.option {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #eee;
}
.prev_next a { display: inline-block; width:80px; text-align:center; margin: 2px; border: 0; padding: 4px; background-color: #666; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="test">
    <div class="prev_next"></div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 1 -</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab slide-0">
        <a href="#">Regular</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab slide-1">
        <a href="#">Athletic</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="prev_next"></div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 2 -</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab slide-0">
        <a href="#">Regular</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab slide-1">
        <a href="#">Athletic</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="prev_next"></div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 3 -</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab slide-0">
        <a href="#">Regular</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab slide-1">
        <a href="#">Athletic</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Since you were targeting **.test** so all the elements with class test was getting the slick method. I changed it to **DOM traversal** using **parent()**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So `$(this).parent().parent().parent().slick` is what's targeting the corresponding slider to the navigation thats clicked? Is there a shorter way of writing that or?

Comment: @user2498890 .. Give me sometime will come back with an alternative solution

Comment: Would this be a better solution? `$(this).parents().eq(2).slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));`

Comment: @user2498890... Here you go with one more solution http://jsfiddle.net/81t4pkfa/155/ .. Instead of traversing use jquery method closest().

Comment: I think either work but thanks for you're help I was getting confused with what I was targeting.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below

```
  $('.each-div').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    prevArrow: "<span class='slick-prev pull-left carousel-btns'><i class='fa fa-angle-left fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>",
    nextArrow: "<span class='slick-next pull-right carousel-btns'><i class='fa fa-angle-right fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>"
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, the only issue I have is I need the text for each navigation to be different. I've updated the demo so you can see. Any idea how I would go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I found a simple solution which finds the slider navigation inside the wrapper.

```
$('.slider-wrap').each(function (index, sliderWrap) {
    var $slider = $(sliderWrap).find('.slider');
    var $next = $(sliderWrap).find('.next');
  var $prev = $(sliderWrap).find('.prev');
    $slider.slick({
        dots: true,
      slidesToShow: 2.5,
        nextArrow: $next,
      prevArrow: $prev
    });
});
```

Pen by Noah Rodenbeek here: https://codepen.io/nominalaeon/pen/gwAdjd